# ASP.net System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.

I'm stuck, guys, Please help me! When I'm trying to add some products on my database there is an exception.
There is my controller code:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
        
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

        public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext db, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _db = db;
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> objList = _db.Product;
            foreach (var obj in objList)
            {
                obj.Category = _db.Category.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == obj.CategoryId);
            }
            return View(objList);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// GET method for CREATE
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IActionResult Upsert(int? id)
        {
            ProductVM productVM = new ProductVM()
            {
                Product = new Product(), 
                CategorySelectList = _db.Category.Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })
            };
        

            if (id == null)
            {
                return View(productVM); //creating
            }
            else
            {
                productVM.Product = _db.Product.Find(id);
                if (productVM.Product == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return View(productVM);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// POST method for CREATE
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
        public IActionResult Upsert(ProductVM productVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
                string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

                if (productVM.Product.Id == 0)
                {
                    string upload = webRootPath + WC.ImagePath;
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    string extention = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, fileName + extention), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }

                    productVM.Product.Image = fileName + extention;
                    _db.Product.Add(productVM.Product);
                }
                else
                {
                   //updating
                }
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
}
```

There is code from View fro Upsert

```
@{
    var title = "Создать продукт";
}

<form method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  *  @if (Model.Product.Id!=0)* //ERROR PLACE
    {
     title = "Edit";   
    <input asp-for="Product.Id" hidden />
    }
    <div class= "border p-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pb-4">@title</h2>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8">

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                           <label asp-for="Product.Name"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Product.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.Price"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input asp-for="Product.Price" class="form-control" />
                             <span asp-validation-for="Product.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                        
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.Description"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <textarea asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control summernote"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.Image"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="file" name="files" id="uploadBox" multiple class="form-control" />
                             
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                            <label asp-for="Product.CategoryId"></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">

                            <select asp-for="Product.CategoryId" asp-items="@Model.CategorySelectList" class="form-control">
                                <option disabled>--Choose category-- </option>
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Product.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-8 offset-4 row p-3">

                            <div class="col">
                                    @if (Model.Product.Id != 0)
                                    {   //update
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info w-100" value="Update"/>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {    //create
                                         <input type="submit" onclick="return validateInput()" class="btn btn-info w-100" value="Create"/>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                   <a asp-action = "Index" class="btn btn-success w-100"> Back </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    @* Keep this empty *@
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    

</form>

@section Scripts 
{
    @{ <partial name = "_ValidationScriptsPartial" />}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.summernote').summernote({height:250});
        });
        function validateInput() {
            if (document.getElementById("uploadBox").value == "") {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Error!',
                    'Please, upload the image!',
                    'error')
                return false;
            }
            else return true;   
        }
    </script>
}
```

Product Model:

```
 public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        
        public string Name { get; set; }

        
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue]
 

        public double Price { get; set; }

       
        public string Image { get; set; }


        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

ProductVM Model

```
 public class ProductVM
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }
    }
```

It's my fist time working with ASP.net and I've tried to follow the steps from the course, but I can't find an error for two days straight, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: which line is giving an exception?

Comment: the one in Upsert.cshtml
 @if (Model.Product.Id!=0)
    {
     title = "Edit Product";   
    <input asp-for="Product.Id" hidden />
    }